# My thunderbird version on 18.04 have emoji bug

Tags: thunderbird, 18.04

Thunderbird mail is full of emoji bug. Every time i scroll. Also i have question why every time a mail come doesn't appear like pop up

[image: one]

and

[image: two]

Comment: I've reported this as a bug <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1770350> - please visit and click "This bug affects me, too"

Comment: This question is most likely a duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 fresh installation, Thunderbird inbox “invaded” by large icons (coloured emojis)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030609/ubuntu-18-04-fresh-installation-thunderbird-inbox-invaded-by-large-icons-col).