# Ubuntu 18.04 fresh installation, Thunderbird inbox "invaded" by large icons (coloured emojis)

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, emoji

From my old HD (Ubuntu 16.04) I copied `~/.thunderbird` and other programs to the new disk with Ubuntu 18.04 installed.
All went good.
I tried to install Opera. The installation was unsuccessful, a window asking something was held.
After that Thunderbird Local Folders -> Inbox (only) was invaded by large icons like this screenshot
[image]
Flowers, plants, trucks and others.
I restarted but those images are still there.
Opera was successfully installed.
What can I do to remove them?

Comment: is this *persisitent* or only when you open certain emails?  Because those look like Emoji icons

Comment: It is persistent only at Inbox list, not in opened emails

Comment: This is caused by bug [Very large emojis displayed in subject line and in the email list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1761844).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-symbola
```

but turns the icons b/w!

From https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/thunderbird-with-huge-icons-emoticons-mate-18-04/16249/23

Here's a way of getting colored icons:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:eosrei/fonts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fonts-twemoji-svginot
```

I did not have to uninstall fonts-symbola for this to work but I don't know how Thunderbird decides which to use.

New font info from http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-color-emoji-linux-google-chrome-noto

Comment: remark: the issue goes away, and so does your colored emojis! (they are the right size, but black and white now). Would be nice to be able to keep colored emoji...

Comment: @Sulliwane thank you for pointing that out - I hadn't noticed! Have edited my original answer to include a color font.

Comment: i like the message: Only Mozilla Firefox/Thunderbird currently support the SVG-in-OpenType
font format required to display these fonts in color. All other
applications will display the included backwards/fallback compatibility
B&W outline glyphs.


More details: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font

End Of Life: https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~eosrei/+archive/ubuntu/fonts
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Comment: and I need to say, this that this font hurts my eyes somehow .. need to play around with the settings in thunderbird ..

Comment: I like black and white - it's less intrusive. So the first line only helped me already. Ideally, I'd find a way to block these things from appearing in subjects completely.

Answer (score 1):

While not a long-term solution (but should work until the fix for [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1761844) is deployed), you can install the [EditEmailSubject](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/edit-email-subject/) add-on for Thunderbird.  It will allow you to delete offending characters from message subjects.

I find the add-on useful generally so this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I downloaded the

> NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf

from here:  https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/tree/master/fonts

and copied it to

> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto

(sudo was required)

then restarted Thunderbird and everything was fine.

References: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1178430