# Some application buttons, emojis and fonts are huge on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icons, fonts, gnome-shell

On my fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME) buttons of some apps are huge. Here's an example - this is VLC. But this problem appears in other apps, for example it applies to emojis in Thunderbird.

How can I fix this?

[image: vlc big buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060594/472085) worked :

> 1. Edit `/etc/environment` with administrator rights.
> 2. Add the following line: `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`
> 3. Reboot your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might solve itself by updating Linux, if you have installed the updates, then you need to install graphics driver and after that set the resolution and adjust the scale and layout in display settings or graphics card management

Comment: I guess you mean "update ubuntu" instead of "update linux kernel". This is not a resolution problem, the other apps are fine and fit well to my 1900×1080 screen. I think it is more like a font rendering problem.

Answer (score 0):

from [Ubuntu 18.04 fresh installation, Thunderbird inbox "invaded" by large icons (coloured emojis)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030609/ubuntu-18-04-fresh-installation-thunderbird-inbox-invaded-by-large-icons-col)

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-symbola
```

to solve this