# VLC shows very big icons and is unusable

Tags: 18.04, vlc, display-resolution

After the update to Ubuntu 18.04, the vlc player can't be used anymore on my second screen(Main screen is 1366x768 and second screen is 1920x1080). When it is dragged from the main screen (where it looks normal) to the second screen, the interface is replaced by a huge ">>" button(see screenshot). I've already deleted and reinstalled vlc. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: attached screenshot]

LE: vlc was installed with

> sudo apt install vlc

the output of `apt-cache policy vlc` is:

```
vlc:
  Installed: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180727+r77135+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Candidate: 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180727+r77135+157~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180727+r77135+157~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     3.0.1-3build1 500
        500 http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Maybe this link to the Ubuntu Forums (and the whole thread before it) can help, [Problem with vlc](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387492&p=13768819#post13768819)

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for the comment. I've added the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VLC installation is from a PPA that provide *unstable* daily builds. Please either

- remove the PPA and revert to the VLC packages provided by Canonical:

  ```
  sudo apt install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily
  ```

  or
- [report the bug to the VideoLAN project](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/) and wait until it is fixed.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

[image: screenshot]

1. Edit `/etc/environment` with administrator rights.
2. Add the following line: `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`
3. Reboot your PC.

[Source](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=144714).